# qsub python import

Tags: python, cluster-computing, importerror

I'm running a job on the cluster for the first time. I run it with the following command:

```
qsub -cwd -S /usr/bin/python myScript.py
```

I have a python script that starts with:

```
import time
import anotherScript
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sge62/default/spool/hpc01/job_scripts/487174", line 11, in <module>
    import anotherScript
ImportError: No module named anotherScript
```

the `anotherScript.py` is in the same directory as `myScript.py`.

What can I do to solve the problem? would appreciate any help

Comment: Note that not all qsub implementations are equal.  I can't find a `-cwd` option on mine although presumably it should run the process in the current working directory and everything should work ... You could `import os; print os.getcwd()` and see what information that tells you.

Comment: well, promlem was solved by `sys.path.append(currentWorkingDirectory)`. However, it's definately not a nice way.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out.  Feel free to post that as an answer when Stack Overflow lets you.  Maybe it could be helpful to someone else later down the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, problem was solved by `sys.path.append(currentWorkingDirectory)`. However, it's definitely not a nice way.